# When select a particular payment method how to add a custom block in order summary block in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, custom-block

When selecting a particular payment method how to add a custom block in the order summary block in checkout page in Magento 2

I used this extension https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee
but I got an issue  404 issue /V1/guest-carts/xcx4SQDhPYJDycVn6lRjgsCuJOGBVswj/set-payment-information-and-get-totals
[image]

Comment: Hey, seeing by the extension you mentioned, you want to add a fee to cash on delivery payment? Is that it? If so you have some option like https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-paymentfee for example. If you need just the block, try to search where that's made in the extension

Comment: I have installed this module and its working well.